# How to know ImageDataGenerator() assigns which label to which image class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, imagedata

For binary classification of cats and dogs images, my directory structure is train_dir/cats and train_dir/dogs.

`train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)`

```
        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/train_dir/',  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(300, 300),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=128,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

        model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
```

How to know the probability return by model.predict() belongs to which class? is Cat=1 or dog=1?
I read somewhere that for multiclass classification returned probabilities are in alphabetical order of class names. But I think that is not the case for binary classification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access `class_indices` variable associated with each `ImageDataGenerator` class. Just print `train_generator.class_indices` to see which class is given which label.